# Passing partial=True down to nested serializer in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have two serializers organised like this:

```
class OuterSerializer():
  inner_obj = InnerSerializer(many=True, required=False)
  other fields ......
```

```
class InnerSerializer():
  field_1 = CharField()
  field_2 = CharField()
```

Now my use case is to partial update the outer serializer's model. How I'm doing that is:

```
   def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = OuterSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': self.request}, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.data
        outerobj = self.service_layer.update(kwargs['pk'], data, request.user)
        response_serializer = OpportunitySerializer(instance=outerobj, context={'request': self.request})
        return Response(response_serializer.data, HTTPStatus.OK)
```

The issue is this partial flag does not get passed down to the InnerSerializer.
For example if my request body looks like below, I want it to work:

```
{"inner_obj":
  {
    "field_1" : "abc"
  }
}
```

Currently I get a 400 error for this saying the field is required.

What I've tried :

1. Setting the partial variable within the OuterSerializer in the init method by modifying it as such

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # We pass the "current serializer" context to the "nested one"
        self.fields['inner_obj'].context.update(self.context)
        self.fields['inner_obj'].partial = kwargs.get('partial')
```

However this doesn't travel down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the `InnerSerializer` so that it could accept the `partial` argument and pass it to its parent, like following:

```py
class InnerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_1 = CharField()
    field_2 = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class OuterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    inner_obj = InnerSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    other fields ......

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.get('partial')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['inner_obj'].child.partial = partial
```

#### Another possible solution.

You can also override the `to_internal_value()` method in the `InnerSerializer` to make it accept `partial` updates so:

```py
class InnerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_1 = CharField()
    field_2 = CharField()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if self.partial:
            return {field: data.get(field, getattr(self.instance, field)) for field in data}
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class OuterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    inner_obj = InnerSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    other fields ......
```

#### Edit:

For the error:

> **KeyError:** "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field field_2`on serializer`InnerSerializer`.

The error message you're encountering suggests that the serializer is trying to access the value for `field_2` from the data, but it's not present.

Currently to solve the error, you should override the `to_representation()` method in the `InnerSerializer` to only include the fields that are present so:

```py
class InnerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_1 = CharField()
    field_2 = CharField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {field: value for field, value in data.items() if value is not None}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves this issue. However, now that i'm not getting the 400 error, there's another error in rest_framework.fields in `to_representation`. `KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `field_2` on serializer `InnerSerializer``. It seems like setting partial=True doesn't take care of it completely